# Changing filetypes with loops and mv

Tags: unix, loops, rename, ksh, mv

I'm trying to take all files of a certain extension, rename them, apply a script to them, and then rename them again. I'm running into something weird.

For the first step of this, I'm trying to apply the following command

```
for f in *.FDC; do mv $f ${f%FDC}FDCTMP1 done
```

Which, I believe, should, for all files of type .FDC, apply the mv function to them, resulting in files renamed as *.FDCTMP1.

When I try to run this, the $ in the command line turns to a >, and I'm unable to do anything. I've run into this problem in the past and I don't really know what's going on. Every time this happens I have to close out my putty instance and start a new one.

The next step is applying my script to the newly renamed .FDCTMP1 files. I'm not quite sure I got this right, but here's what I'm trying:

```
for f in *.FDCTMP1; do more $f | a bunch of sed and awk stuff here
```

I was originally testing this script with more filename | sed & awk stuff, and wasn't positive how I would change that functionality to taking each filename in the loop.

then, I want to apply the same idea as in step 1, to rename the filetype again:

```
for f in *.FDCTMP1; do mv $f ${f%FDCTMP1}FDCTMP2 done
```

I think I supplied too much info about my problem, I think the main issue is this part:

```
for f in *.FDC;
```

If it's relevant, I'm in kornshell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt changes from $PS1 to $PS2 because the `for` command has not seen `done` -- you're missing a semi-colon after the mv command:

```
for f in *.FDC; do mv $f ${f%FDC}FDCTMP1 done
#---------------------------------------^
```

It sounds like you don't need 3 loops

```
for f in *.FDC; do
    tmp1=${f}TMP1
    mv "$f" "$tmp1"
    # do stuff with "$tmp1"
    mv "$tmp1" "${f}TMP2"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In this command line:

```
for f in *.FDC; do mv $f ${f%FDC}FDCTMP1 done
```

you're missing the semi-colon before `done`:

```
for f in *.FDC; do mv $f ${f%FDC}FDCTMP1; done
```

As it was, you'd written code to pass three arguments to `mv`, and the shell was still looking for `done` as the first word of a command.  You can type `done` on a line on its own, or after a semi-colon (or after an `&` that places a command in background).